# Oracle homework cannot get "...THEN TO_CHAR" to work?

Tags: oracle

I am working the following question for my Oracle class. I have the solution below, that works, but I would like to format the dollar output. When I add the "TO_CHAR" statement, I get an error that "FROM" is not where expected.

**Homework assignment question:**

Use the Oracle database employees table and CASE expression to decode the department id. Display the department id, last name, salary and a column called “New Salary” whose value is based on the following conditions:
    If the department id is 10 then 1.25 * salary
    If the department id is 90 then 1.5 * salary
    If the department id is 130 then 1.75 * salary
Otherwise, display the old salary.

**Working statement WITHOUT the "TO_CHAR":**

```
SELECT LAST_NAME AS "LAST NAME", DEPARTMENT_ID AS "DEPARTMENT ID", SALARY,
CASE DEPARTMENT_ID
WHEN 10 THEN SALARY * 1.25
WHEN 90 THEN SALARY * 1.50
WHEN 130 THEN SALARY * 1.75
ELSE SALARY END AS "NEW SALARY"
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

**Statement that errors out:**

```
SELECT LAST_NAME AS "LAST NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID AS "DEPARTMENT ID", SALARY,
CASE DEPARTMENT_ID
WHEN 10 THEN TO_CHAR (SALARY*1.25, '$99,999.99')
WHEN 90 THEN TO_CHAR (SALARY*1.50, '$99,999.99')
WHEN 130 THEN TO_CHAR (SALARY*1.75, '$99,999.99')
ELSE SALARY END AS "NEW SALARY"
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

THANKS!

**Result after correction below:**

LAST NAME   DEPARTMENT ID   SALARY  NEW SALARY
King                90          24000   $36,000.00
Kochhar             90          17000   $25,500.00
De Haan             90          17000   $25,500.00

Comment: You have a typo in your second statement : you forgot to put " after LAST NAME. Is it just here ?

Comment: you're right, the answer below will still be usefull, but after that correction only !

Comment: +1 for admitting that its a homework problem

Comment: also, please list the actual ORA error you're getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craig's explanation of the problem is correct, but instead of just adding yet another TO_CHAR, I would say wrap the whole CASE expression in a single TO_CHAR:

```
SELECT LAST_NAME AS "LAST NAME", DEPARTMENT_ID AS "DEPARTMENT ID", SALARY,
TO_CHAR(
 CASE DEPARTMENT_ID
 WHEN 10 THEN SALARY * 1.25
 WHEN 90 THEN SALARY * 1.50
 WHEN 130 THEN SALARY * 1.75
 ELSE SALARY END,
 '$99,999.99'
 ) AS "NEW SALARY"
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Comment: First off... thanks to everyone for the quick responses! I like this approach, however, it only applies the formatting to the second salary column and not the first? Please see the edit above. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin -- well, yeah, the TO_CHAR only applies to the expression that is inside it.  If you also want the base salary column to be formatted, put a TO_CHAR expression around that as well.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose if I would have thought about it for say 5 seconds, I would have realized it. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you make a to_char on salary in the ELSE statement ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your WHEN / THEN cases are returning a string (since you are using TO_CHAR), but your ELSE is returning a number.  Just add the TO_CHAR to the ELSE as well.